# Change selectbox depending on radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**I want to change the content of a selectbox based on a radio button**.

I'm using **AngularJS**. So, my select box looks like this:

```
<select ng-controller="MyController">
    <option ng-repeat="o in array_of_values" value="{{o.id}}">{{o.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Now, **depending on wether my radio button is checked or not, I want a different set of values loaded in the select box.**

I don't have much experience with Angular, but I suspect I could dynamically change `$scope.array_of_values` in `MyController`. Something similar to [this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) (official documentation)

I've seen [another example](http://codepen.io/SusanneLundblad/pen/iBhoJ), where you can change the content of a div based on a radio button, just using `ng-model + ng-show`

**EDITED**: But I have another difficulty: I **really have several pairs radio button / select box, as table's rows, and they are dynamically generated**. I could **use plain jQuery plus a javascript function to get the id of each radio button and just change a specific select box based on the `onClick` event of the radio button**. But I tend to think there is a more elegant way to do this, using AngularJS. Am I right?

**Any clues? What approach should I follow?**

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should start by reading the doc and pick the right components.

Select angular way: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Radio: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

$watch the radio models and change the array_of_values values. Prefer use object agains values ({id:0, value:"value0"}).

```
$scope.radio = {name:"Radio1"};
$scope.$watch('radio', function(newVal, lastVal){ 
       if(newVal.name === 'radio2') 
            $scope.array_of_values = values2 
       };
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My main problem is the rows are dynamically generated. So, their ids/names aren't known in advance. I guess I could generate a sequence for the names, but not sure about how.